# Typed dataset codebehind

Tags: .net, strongly-typed-dataset

What can you add to the codebehind file of a typed dataset? I thought the dataset classes were generated at runtime. The codebehind file is always an empty partial class.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably add anything you like as it is a class but since an autogenerated file could be regenerated again if you touch the dataset designer, in case you want to add some methods i would add another file by hand having it to extend the same partial class so visual studio will never overwrite this last file as it was added by you.

Anyway what do you want to add? dont make same mistake I did long ago to consider these st datasets as business objects or business managers they are ONLY typed data containers...